# Django model recursive relationship

Tags: django, recursion, models, relationship

1. Why would I create a recursive relationship?
  ```
      aField = models.ForeignKey('self')
  ```
2. Is this the same with the above?

```
        class aClass(models.Model):  
        aField = models.ForeignKey('aClass')
```

Comment: I do not understand your first question. "Why would I create...". We don't know why.

Comment: 1. If yours model objects should form some kind of relationship i.e. in a tree every object beside root should have a parent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You may need to create a recursive relationship when you would like to have parent and child nodes with identical model structure. For example if you have comments with text, data and user_id:

   ```
   class Comment( models.Model ):
       text = models.TextField()
       create_date_time = models.DateTimeField()
       parent_comment = models.ForeignKey( 'self' )
   ```
2. I think yes (you can try to test it) but it's not a good form. If you change a class name then you must change the string value in brackets. If you use 'self' you haven't this headache.