# Is it possible to have the same model for its own field in Django but have multiple instead of one?

Tags: django, model, geolocation

I'm making an app where I have City model. I need to add nearby_cities field. City can have multiple nearby cities. How would I make such field? Also what would be the best approach to my problem? Should I have a NearbyCity model?

Thanx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django model recursive relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182721/django-model-recursive-relationship)

Answer (score 1):

It's seems to me that what you need is a simple Many-to-many relationship since each city can have many nearby cities. For instance:

```
nearby_cities = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
```

If you want to store additional information about the relationship you'll have to create another model and use it to link both instances of your city model using [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/)

Check [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for more information about the many-to-many relationship too.

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is what I needed. However, are there any performance drawbacks when using ManyToManyField? I remember someone telling me about performance regarding that. To be honest, I don't have many cities which will have nearby cities so I was thinking to actually have CharField where I'll have nearby cities stored as string but separated with commas ("Boston,Waltham,Old Town"). So I would split that string and then get an object for each city.

Comment: Many to many is a common thing in databases, I don't think you should care about this. But, if you can estimate the number of nearby cities you could have attributes to each city, for instance: 
    nearby_city1 = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True)
    nearby_city2 = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True)
    nearby_city3 = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True)
if the city has just 2 nearby cities, the third one would be null